# Need help in writing JUnit test case for CQ5.4 application

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, aem, sling

I am writing JUnit test cases for CQ5 application using JMockito and sling commons testing api. I am able to mock Request parameters. My actual java methods has some logic to iterate Request parameters map for example requestParamMapObj.keySet().iterator() and to get some nodes properties.But when I run the Unit test case the said keySet iterator is not getting executed and throwing target invocation exception even the requestParamMapObj has the data.

This is first time I am writing JUnit test cases for content management application.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Here is my test method code:

```
this.context.checking(new Expectations() {
    { 
        this.one(mockRequest).getRequestParameterMap();
        this.will(returnValue(paramsMap)); 
    } 
});
```

and when the Junit reaches to the below code it is throwing target invocation exception.

```
private Map<String, String> getAllAnswers(final RequestParameterMap reqParamMap) { 
    final Iterator<String> keySetIterator1 = reqParamMap.keySet().iterator();
}
```

Comment: that exception has nothing to with CQ5. Post your code! It is hard to identify the cause without it.

Comment: Here is my test method code this.context.checking(new Expectations() {
    {
    this.one(mockRequest).getRequestParameterMap();
    this.will(returnValue(paramsMap));
    }
   }); and when the Junit reaches to the below code it is throwing target invocation exception. private Map<String, String> getAllAnswers(final RequestParameterMap reqParamMap) {
  final Iterator<String> keySetIterator1 =  reqParamMap.keySet().iterator();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Shawn. You are right, when I set up the expectations for keySet() method it is being invoked. 
this.allowing(paramsMap).keySet(); 
But my question here is we need to set up expectations for every behavior. does this makes meaningful, I mean the unit test code is becoming more than actual java code :) .
Do we have any alternate solution so that we can reduce the test code.

```
            this.allowing(resource).adaptTo(Node.class);
            this.will(returnValue(node));

            this.allowing(node).hasNode("voting");
            this.will(returnValue(true));

            allowing(repository).loginAdministrative(null);
            will(returnValue(session));

            allowing(session).getWorkspace();
            will(returnValue(workspace));

            allowing(workspace).getQueryManager();
            will(returnValue(queryManager));
```

Comment: When you use a mock object, you typically have to set up the expectations for every method you expect to be invoked on that mock object.  Some methods can indeed have more test code than the actual code being tested--especially if you are using references to abstract CQ5 class and calling lots of their methods in your code.  An alternate solution might be to create a concrete class that derives from whatever class you are mocking out and then override its methods--but that will also take some work and may be more brittle. BTW, be sure to mark my answer as the answer if that was indeed it. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the full code, but based on what you listed and your commment so far it sounds like perhaps you need to set up the expectations for what will happen when the keySet() method is invoked.  I suspect perhaps you have a mocked out the ParameterMap object, but perhaps have not set up the expectations on that ParameterMap so that when its keySet method is invoked it will know what to do/return.  Again, I am kindof just guessing, but I hope this will help.